# Indexed Set Problem "Richard Hammack: Book of Proof"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is question 10.a in section 1.8

$$\bigcup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}[x,1]\times[0,x^2]$$

So far I am thinking about two answers. This first is simply $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Graphically, this would be the set of all points on the region from $0\le x \le 1$, and $0 \le y \le 1$. When searching online, I saw some people going with this answer.

However, I am thinking that the answer should be $\{(x,y)|x \in [0,1], 0\le y\le x^2\}$. Graphically this would be all the points in the region from $0\le x \le 1$, bounded above by the parable $y=x^2$.

Any help/hints would be useful.

Comment: Drag the $x$-coordinate in [this interactive graphic](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yw4whdtqey) to help you visualize the answer.